# How to query without doing N+1 query in MySQL

Tags: mysql

i have 2 tables

```
users_table
id | first_name
1 | first name1
2 | first name2

addresses_table
id | user_id | address
1 | 1 | first address of user 1
2 | 1 | second address of user 1
3 | 2 | first address of user 2
4 | 2 | second address of user 2
```

I want a table result like this, first column is the users_table first_name and the second column are the hobbies of each user separated by comma

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>first name1</td><td>first address of user 1, second address of user 1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>first name2</td><td>first address of user 2, second address of user 2</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

if i have to query it will have to `select * from users_table` then get the addresses of each user like `select * from addresses_table where user_id = 1` which is not very efficient, this can be prevented with ORMs but i want to know we can prevent N+1 query using SQL

Comment: Were you trying to use html to represent the desired output? Or dif you want the output in html

Comment: Look up `group_concat`

Comment: No. Not group_concat :-(

Comment: use join and ordering? Leave the formatting part to the presentation layer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the below query

select first_name , group_concat(address,',') as address 
from 
users_table usrTable 
join
addresses_table addTable on usrTable.id = addTable.user_id
group by first_name